# How to get and include the CSRF token in the header when working with REST API

Tags: django, rest, reactjs, axios

I am using python Django for creating the REST API's.The client side is developed in react and is made as a standalone app.I am uisng axios for triggering th http request.I nedd to pass th CSRF token with every post request,But not able to get the CSRF token from the browser.

Comment: the CSRF token is available as a cookie. What's the question exactly? How to get it from the browser using React?

Comment: The csrf token is not getting saved as cookie in my browser

Comment: This can occur if `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True` is present in your `settings.py` and you are accessing the site non-securely, eg from localhost.

Comment: Yeah..it worked,Now i can see the cookie in browser console.But not able to  fetch it using document.cookie

Comment: Did you check django doc. & Javascript code to retrieve cookie https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

Comment: check JS **getCookie** function in django documentation.

Comment: I checked it,but it is printing a empty line in  the console

Comment: Empty? Do you have the django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware in your middlewares list, do you have CSRF_USE_SESSIONS in your settings (should be false)?

Answer (score 0):

**How to pass your CSRF when doing Ajax request?**

First, make sure you have the django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware in your middlewares list in your settings file. This middleware sets the CSRF_TOKEN in the cookie so you can retrieve it for your ajax request.

Second, Django can now store the CSRF in the session. However, in your particular case you don't want the CSRF_TOKEN in the session. Make sure you have CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False (which is the default) to have the CSRF in the cookie.

If you check the cookies you should now have a CSRF_TOKEN in there. You can add it dynamically to your ajax request IF you are using jquery with the following code.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

I'm saying IF you use Jquery because you are using React, which doesn't need Jquery to do Ajax request, it's up to you how you do them.

Comment: I may be wrong here but, when setting `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False`, aren't you basically storing the SECRET in the cookie, whereas it would normally be in the session? I've tried using the cookie and all my mutating http requests keep getting rejected. I thought I was sending the token correctly, but I'm now assuming it's because the cookie is actually the CSRF secret, not the token. Furthermore, if the CSRF cookie is indeed a token, then how can I use it with the sessions if the only cookie I get back is a session ID?